# split string by comma and display it after format it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example i have some HTML elements like below

```
<p> apple,banana,oranger</p>
```

and i'd like to use the javascript to make it like

```
<p>apple</p> <p>banana</p> <p>orange</p>
```

How may i achieve this?

**UPDATE 1:**

I am using other methods to do my task due to some reaseon and it looks as like below

```
var node = document.getElementById('discovereedKeywords');
node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '<p class="tag-item">');
```

and in reality those `<p>` tags are actually generate by a for loop, but my method only change the first node it found therefore i tried

Consider the html looks like this

```
 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> apple,banana,oranger</p>

 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> apple,oranger,oranger</p>

 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> kiwi,melon,pinapple</p>
```

Javascript

```
for (var i=0; i <data.result.data.length; i++){

    var node[i] = document.getElementByClassName('discovereedKeywords');
    node[i].innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '<p class="tag-item">');

                }

            }
```

but this those work, why?

Comment: Use `","` instead of the `" "` in the duplicate and wrap in `<p>` instead of a span. You likely want to [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) the `<p>` you had in the beginning

Comment: It can be done without using jquery though. 

`<html>
<body>
 <p id="test"> apple,banana,orange </p>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('test');
var el_content = el.innerHTML.trim().split(',');
console.log( )
console.log(el_content)
var tmp = "";
for (var e = 0; e < el_content.length; e++){
 tmp += "<p>"+el_content[e]+"</p>";
}
el.outerHTML=tmp;
</script>`

Comment: Where do you close `</p>` ?

Comment: i know there's some syntax error

Comment: but i'd still like to know how could i make it works on every element has the class discovereedKeywords

Comment: and actually it close those </p> automatically

Answer (score 2):

Use `.split` to split the `string` in array. `.join` the array in string by concatenating `</p></p>` in between items. Wrap the string in `<p>`

```js
$('p').get(0).outerHTML = ('<p>' + $('p').text().split(',').join('</p><p>') + '</p>');
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>apple,banana,oranger</p>
```

*OR using `Array#map` without `jQuery`*

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('demo');
elem.outerHTML = elem.textContent.split(',').map(function(el) {
  return '<p>' + el + '</p>';
}).join('');
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='demo'>apple,banana,oranger</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
$('#p').html(function(i, v) {
    return '<p class="discovereedKeywords">' + v.split(',').join('</p><p class="discovereedKeywords">') + '</p>'; // update the html content
  })
  .children() // get children p
  .unwrap(); // unwrap the parent p
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p">apple,banana,oranger</p>
```

---

Or use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** here

```js
$('#p').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/([^,]+)(?:,|$)/g, '<p class="discovereedKeywords">$1</p>')
  })
  .children() // get children p
  .unwrap(); // unwrap the parent p
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p">apple,banana,oranger</p>
```

Comment: @anson920520 : updated